# UV texture is stretched out, how to fix?

Tags: texturing, uv

So I have placing the image textures sorted to position with my UVs, however now I can't sort why the images themselves are distorted. You can see that "walk-sonic" is stretched vertically (it's too tall) and the "dial" section is compressed horizontally. (probably a bit tricky to see the text in the pic - the other should be easily seen).

I made the texture image just a big square and I don't know if it needs to be a specific size or ratio?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in another thread by Kura.

"Few months late, but in case anyone else needs it: if your UV maps are coming out stretched, try going back into object mode and applying object transforms, then try unwrapping again. Usually, this takes care of the issue when it occurs for me, and is the first thing I try if my UVs are stretching."